# Issues in binding dynamic json to input controls, view is not getting refreshed with latest/dynamic data

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I am not able to bind the dynamic data to the input controls, but static data is bound to the same controls properly. the dynamic data is retreived and I am able to view the data using console.log. but the values are not bound. snapshot of the browser console with the data display
[image]
my static data which bind properly looks like below

```
const SAMPLE = { queueId: 11, name: 'Mr. Nice' };
constructor(){
this.resultData = SAMPLE;
}
```

the above hardcoded static data is bound with input controls, but dynamic data which is retreived using Http services is having issues
after the http service call, i tried writing to console.log and I can see the content in the browser console. but it is not get bound with input controls
I am using TemplateUrl to refer the html file.
HTML tag to bind

```
<input type="text" name="txtQueueID" class="form-control" id="txtQueueID" [(ngModel)]="resultData.queueId" />
```

code to fetch the data using services

```
 GetExtractorQueuesByID(_extractorQueueID) {
        console.log("Inside GetExtractorQueuesByID method in ExtractorQueueDetails");
        this._CacheDataService.GetExtractorQueuesByID(_extractorQueueID)
            .subscribe(
            (res) => {
                this.resultData = res;

            },
            (error) => console.log("error : " + error),
            () => console.log('Error in GetExtractorQueuesByID in ExtractorQueueDetails : ' + Error)
            );
    }
```

My service which makes http request

```
public GetExtractorQueuesByID = (queudID): Observable<ExtractorQueueItem> => {
    console.log("Inside method GetExtractorQueuesByID");

    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    console.log("API URL: " + this.BLUESKYDATACACHEAPI_GETEXTRACTORQUEUEBYID + queudID);

    return this._http.get(this.BLUESKYDATACACHEAPI_GETEXTRACTORQUEUEBYID + queudID, { headers: headers })
        .map(Response => Response.json())
        .catch(this.HandleError);
}
```

**My guess is the view is not getting refreshed with latest json data bound with it. How to make sure i refresh the view or rebind the view? any ideas ?**

Comment: can you post the code where you fetch the data?

Comment: queueId is not present in your json object. So how d you get it in input?

Comment: it is available, the earlier image was not showing the entire properties. refer the latest image

Answer (score 0):

`queueId` property is not available in retrieved json object. So you need to change it to one of object's available properties.

E.g

```
[(ngModel)]="resultData.customerId"
```